# JavaScript Math.sin and Math.cos return wrong values

Tags: javascript, math

i'm developing a simple application to help my math teacher to teach about trigonometry. The application is nothing but a circle where the angle keeps spinning and shows the variation of the Sin and Cos. Simple as hell.

This is what i have so far:

[image]

And this is what i want to achieve

[image]

(notice the green part representing the cos).

Everything is being built through CSS. I needed to calculate the height and the width of the green triangle so i could display it, i tought it would be as simple as calculating the sin and the cos and just multiplying it by 200(my circle radius in px).
But for some reason js is giving me inaccurate values for the sin and cos.
For example, it gives right values if my angle is 0(cos: 1, sen: 0). But if i use an angle like 90, it will not return the right values, as shows the screenshot below:

[image]

This is my code so far(reduced for readability)

```
function trig()
{
    [...]
    this.radianMultiplier = Math.PI / 180;

    this.setDegree = function(degree)
    {
        [...]

        $('#h').html( Math.sin(degree * this.radianMultiplier) );
        $('#w').html( Math.cos(degree * this.radianMultiplier) );
    }
}
```

Any thoughts on what might be happening?

Comment: The screenshot is unreadable, can you just show the numbers?

Comment: How is the triangle being rendered? What are the invalid height and width values being returned?

Comment: @Barmar To angle 0 (sin: 0, cos: 1). To angle 90 (sin: 1, cos: 6.123031769111886e-17).

Comment: That's just floating point imprecision. See [Is JavaScript's Floating-Point Math Broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: @Aiias Same as above(To angle 0 (sin: 0, cos: 1). To angle 90 (sin: 1, cos: 6.123031769111886e-17)). I'm not rendering the triangle yet, just trying to figure out why i get incorrect values from the sin/cos function. The problem can be reproduced on Opera, Chrome and IE(don't have Firefox right now to try it out).

Comment: `6.123031769111886e-17` is very close to `0`. Is there a particular reason why you would stray from rounding, say 4 decimal places?

Comment: @BillyMoon I tried it in Chrome and I get the same 6e-17 he got.

Comment: Alright, i'm sorry for the double posting. Marked as duplicate so it can be closed.